# mongoose Update always gives me TypeError: Cannot set property '__v' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

I'm trying to update a socketId to '' whenever a user is disconnect. But for somehow I always getting this error

```
update.$setOnInsert[this.schema.options.versionKey] = 0;
                                                        ^
TypeError: Cannot set property '__v' of undefined
```

For example my goal if someone is disconnect

```
socketId = ZH_Ic0zD8QkmNYuJAAAE;
will be
socketId = '';
```

Here's the code

```
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log(socket.id);
    var disconnectSocketId = '';
    User.findOneAndUpdate({socketId: socket.id}, disconnectSocketId, {upsert: true, new: true}, function(err, doc) {
      if (err) {
        return console.error
      }

      console.log(doc.socketId);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

**Update**: The issue with passing `socket.id` as the `query` object is obviously already fixed regarding the latest edit of your question.

Most importantly, the TypeError signalizes that there's obviously no object `update.$setOnInsert` (I understand that `this.schema.options.versionKey` holds the string `"__v"`), so you're trying to assign a property to an undefined object. You should first initialize it in some way:

```
var update = {
  $setOnInsert: {},
  $set: {}
  ...
}
```

If I got you right, you want to pass the `$setOnInsert` object as part of the document object to `findOneAndUpdate()`, right? Your function parametrization looks wrong: `disconnectSocketId` should hold the document object with fields to be updated but you're passing just an empty string. Also just passing `socket.id` as the query object doesn't look correct. Furthermore: Are you sure you want to update a record by clearing an identifier...?  And finally: Be aware if you pass your fields to be updated using `$setOnInsert` that this wouldn't actually update your data if the record you queried for already exists (i.e. having that ID).

Assuming that `update` represents the object holding the information about fields and how they should be updated, I think you're trying to do something similar like this:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({ socketId: socket.id }, update, { upsert: true, new: true }, function(err, doc) {
  ...
}
```

Please be sure to check the [mongoDB docs for $setOnInsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) and [mongoose docs for findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate)

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer this, the reason why I want to update socketId is because I have socketId field in User Schema. So whenever a specific user that has the same socketId value disconnected, then I want his socketId to be empty string or null.

Comment: Currently I'm using a normal find then save method to solve this problem

Comment: @JackMoscovi Okay, but did you try using `findOneAndUpdate` with a corrected parametrization set? And: Wouldn't it make more sense to update a boolean field `valid` and just leave the original value of `socketId`  untouched if a user disconnects?